# Function only call once in button click. Want the function to be executed every button click

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Hi I am new to jspdf and html. I would really appreciate any advice. My code below is working fine; however, it is only working once when my button is clicked.  And if I click it second time, it won't work anymore. I need to refresh the page to make it work again. The function is only called once but not everytime the button clicked. I want it to work everytime I click the button. I can download the pdf multiple times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>PDF</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Content Area -->
        <div id="print">
            <p></p>
            <p id="veewom"></p>
            <p></p>
            <p id="veewom1"></p>
            <p></p>
            <p id="veewom2"></p>
            <p></p>
            <p id="veewom3"></p>
            <p></p>
            <p id="veewom4"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-btn"></div>
        <button onclick="function" type="button"  id="download">Download</button>
        <!-- Script -->
        <script>

    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#p-btn': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#download').click(function () {
      var chars = $('#try1').val();
      var chars1 = $('#name').val();

      var source = $('#print').html();
      doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });

    doc.setDrawColor(0);
    doc.setFillColor(128, 128, 128);
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.setFontType('bold');
    doc.text('Name                              :', 12, 30);
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.setFontType('normal');
    doc.text(chars1, 80, 30);
    doc.save('test.pdf');
    });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi have you tried removing the `onclick="function"` attribute from your button?

Comment: and add the jquery library too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute
`onclick="function"` from that button with an id `download`,add the jquery library `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` right after where you added the jspdf and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove attribute `onclick="function"` you're setting click listener with jquery

Move initialization doc inside function click

Use `let` keyword for secure use of instances and avoid conflicts

```
<button type="button" id="download">Download</button>
<!-- Script -->
<script>

$('#download').click(
  function downloadClickfunction () {
    // make instance everytime and use let
    let doc = new jsPDF();

    /* etc ...*/
    let source = $('#print').html();
    doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

    /* etc ...*/

    doc.save('test.pdf');
  } 
);


</script>
```